# INSERT INTO SELECT if NOT EXISTS in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

I have this below query. I like to insert only if the row is not present in TABLE1. How can I do that?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE, ACV_VOLUME)
SELECT VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ACV_VEHICLE_DETAILS
WHERE YEAR     = table2 .veh_year
AND MAKE       = table2 .veh_make
) AS ACV_VOLUME
FROM TABLE2 table2 WHERE VEH_YEAR IS NOT NULL AND VEH_MAKE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Do a left join on table 1 and filter for nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE, ACV_VOLUME)
    SELECT VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE, 
           (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM ACV_VEHICLE_DETAILS vd
            WHERE vd.YEAR = t2.veh_year AND vd.MAKE = t2.veh_make
           ) AS ACV_VOLUME
    FROM TABLE2 t2 
    WHERE VEH_YEAR IS NOT NULL AND VEH_MAKE IS NOT NULL AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM table1 t1
                      WHERE t1.veh_year = t2.veh_year and t1.veh_make = t2.veh_make
                     );
```

Comment: I still see multiple rows of "1981 CHEVROLET 0" in my select query

Comment: The rows are presumably not exact duplicates.  Most likely, the `veh_make` has extra characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MERGE` with `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT`:

```
merge into Table1 t
using (
   SELECT VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE,
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ACV_VEHICLE_DETAILS
    WHERE YEAR     = table2 .veh_year
    AND MAKE       = table2 .veh_make
   ) AS ACV_VOLUME
   FROM TABLE2 table2 WHERE VEH_YEAR IS NOT NULL AND VEH_MAKE IS NOT NULL
) d
on (t.veh_year = d.veh_year and t.veh_make = d.veh_make)
when not matched then insert (veh_year, veh_make, acv_volume)
                      values (d.veh_year, d.veh_make, d.acv_volume);
```

Don't forget to commit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
INSERT  INTO TABLE1 ( VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE, ACV_VOLUME)
SELECT  VEH_YEAR
      , VEH_MAKE
      , ( SELECT    COUNT(*)
          FROM      ACV_VEHICLE_DETAILS
          WHERE     YEAR = t2.veh_year
                AND MAKE = t2.veh_make
         ) AS ACV_VOLUME
FROM    TABLE2 t2
WHERE   VEH_YEAR IS NOT NULL
    AND VEH_MAKE IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM  Table1 t1 
                    WHERE t1.VEH_YEAR = t2.VEH_YEAR
                      AND t1.VEH_MAKE = t2.VEH_MAKE
                      );
```

This assumes you want to exclude only when both the `VEH_MAKE` and `VEH_YEAR` are already present, if you want to exclude from `INSERT` all records based on `VEH_MAKE` alone you just alter the correlating `WHERE` criteria, excluding `t1.VEH_YEAR = t2.VEH_YEAR`

Answer (score 0):

Classic `LEFT JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE, ACV_VOLUME)
SELECT VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE, ACV_VOLUME 
FROM(SELECT VEH_YEAR, VEH_MAKE,
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM ACV_VEHICLE_DETAILS
            WHERE YEAR = table2.veh_year
            AND MAKE = table2.veh_make) AS ACV_VOLUME
     FROM TABLE2 table2 WHERE VEH_YEAR IS NOT NULL AND VEH_MAKE IS NOT NULL
    )t
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1 on t.VEH_YEAR = t1.VEH_YEAR AND t.VEH_MAKE = t1.VEH_MAKE AND t.ACV_VOLUME = t1.ACV_VOLUME
WHERE t1.VEH_YEAR IS NULL
```